# "He feared a U.S. invasion" vs. "He feared U.S. invasion"

Tags: differences, articles, indefinite-articles, zero-article

It it accurate to say this?

> He feared a U.S. invasion.

Or should I say,

> He feared U.S. invasion.

I'm trying to figure out when to place "a" in front of the U.S. when U.S. comes with a noun like invasion/attack/sanctions. What is the difference?

Comment: I've edited your question and asked for it to be reopened. FYI, you  can edit questions too. A general answer can be [found here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/are-there-specific-rules-to-build-expressions-with-or-without-articles).

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the second option on socio-political grounds:

> "He feared U.S. invasion"

Because, as opposed to an attack, an invasion is a drawn out process, and the indefinite article excessively encapsulates it. I would compare this to saying,

> I fear **an afterschool detention** is in store for me

or

> I fear **punishment** is in store for me

While my punishment could be a detention, the idea of punishment doesn't imply a finite action like a one-hour detention.

You don't lose any meaning between "a U.S. invasion" and "U.S. invasion" but, contextually, I imagine that a person who fears invasion does not only fear the finite action that occurs when borders are breached but the attendant occupation of the territory, which comprises a drawn-out and nearly undefinable period of time--perhaps, even a permanent condition owing to the leftover cultural and religious residue from the expelled invaders.

Comment: It is surely possible to imagine somebody who would welcome U.S. invasion (since even foreign military rule would be better than the present situation) but fear *the* actual invasion (since there is likely to be shooting).

Comment: @Tim: It is. And it's part of the utilitarian narrative we Americans hear routinely from our congress.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to figure out when to place "a" in front of the U.S. when U.S. comes with a noun like invasion/attack/sanctions. What is the difference?

Why the U.S. specifically? Do I smell a political position there? :)

**In any case,**

What makes the U.S. (as a nation's name) a bit special is that it's hard to make into a differentiated adjective (vs. *Europe/European* or *Canada/Canadian*, for example).

Here's my knee-jerk for each of your mentioned words (*sanctions*, *attack*, *invasion*):

> They feared U.S. sanctions. (*Can't be done otherwise since 'sanctions' is plural anyway'*).
>
> They feared a U.S. attack.
>
> They feared U.S. invasion.

I don't think there's a general rule for these type of expressions; you'll probably have to learn them by idiom.

Comment: _an invasion by **the** US or **the** former USSR_ vs _an invasion by Canada_