# which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

- "I play a drum."
- "I play the drum."
- "I play the drums."

My context book says it is the third one but I saw foreigners use the other choices before. So which one of the four choices is acceptable?

Comment: How many drums do you play?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Omission of definite article with musical instruments](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6635/2303).

Comment: All of them are _grammatically_ correct, but the third one is the most _idiomatic_ if you are the percussionist in a band. The others might possibly used when describing a performance in which you played a single drum, such as the [Toy Symphony](https://www.classicalmpr.org/story/2015/07/16/toy-symphony)

Answer (score -1):

I have not heard the indefinite article with an instrument, so I would not say "I play a drum." However, you could say:

> I play the drums.

Here, *drums* is an abbreviation for a *drum set*. (Think of snare + cymbals + bass drum = drum set).

"I play the drum" is a little marginal, because of the abbreviation. But I have seen other instruments used, as in "I play the viola."

Comment: It is like "I love music; I  feed dogs... etc." Why any article before 'drum'? Let it naturally sound, "I play drum" similar to I play violin. 'a' or 'the' gives a little different meaning.

Comment: The link cited in the main question, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6635/omission-of-definite-article-with-musical-instruments, answer your query about the article.

Comment: @RamPillai that is acceptable in certain contexts, but only if you are playing one drum. Most drummer have a drum kit, which has multiple drums, so the idiomatic way is "I play the drums" or "I play drums".

Comment: Yeah, that way you are right.